# Wicket Passing parameters between Pages

Tags: parameters, wicket

I am new to wicket. I have a wicket application class from which has Login page as the home page. after Login user is taken to a page (page X) where user selects the system (user can have access to multiple systems) where user wants to navigate.

Now for a new requirement, client would be given URL with specific system Id. If the URL has that  parameter (e.g. ...?system=22), login page would get that parameter. Post login user would be taken  to the system (22) screen and the in between page (page X) would be skipped. To achieve this I need to pass the parameter from login to the next page (page X) which would auto select the system and takes the user to system (22) screen.

What is the best way to pass parameters from one page to another page. Is following the correct way:

from first page after successful login:

setResponsePage(NextPage.class, params);

Params would have the system Id.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes.

And in the target page class there has to be a constructor that accepts `PageParameters`.

However in the special case of a login page this isn't a good idea as there are several ready-made solutions. [This](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/projects/authroles.html) for example. Even if you don't want to use them, you can still use the built-in [intercept page](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/using-intercept-pages.html) support.

Comment: thanks for the response. However I am not sure why you recommended for intercept page. User would alsways come to login page first before going to page X. Please add more thoughts around it

Comment: The user might have bookmarked a later page. You don't want them to be able to access that page without logging in first.

Comment: ok. In my case they would be sent a bookmarkable url through email only. I am facing another issue where my home page is being called twice due to which I am not able to get the url parameter in the second iteration. Any idea how can i get the url parameter in the second run of the constructor